# Cart becomes empty if Console is opened in Chrome

Tags: magento-1.9, session

We have a strange issue on onepage checkout:

If developer console is opened in our Google chrome browser, When we are come to onepage checkout method, we are getting the error captured in console as below

[image: Console Error]

I investigated this issue and found below,

On `app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\controllers\OnepageController.php` under `protected function _expireAjax()` method `$this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->hasItems()` gives null. Which means that shopping cart is empty.

My question is why does this error occur only when console opened in Google Chrome browser?

Also, sometime I am directing to Shopping cart empty page. It also not happens all the times, sometimes, lets say 4 out of 10 times. As per other posts I adjust all cookie settings from the backend. But no luck,

Edit:

1. Yes the site is enabled with `www.`
2. Cookie settings as below

   `Cookie Lifetime: 3600
   Cookie Path: /
   Cookie Domain: .<MY_DOMAIN.COM>
   Use HTTP Only: Yes
   Cookie Restriction Mode: No`

Any suggestion on this?

Comment: This is likely only observed with Inspector open, and not caused by it being open. Session issues are complex and hard to debug. Can you provide information about your session and cookie settings? Are you using a multi-server environment? Does your site's domain use www.?

Comment: @TylerV. I updated my question, kindly check

Comment: If the live site is on www. and you have a dev site on dev. and your cookie domain is set to .domain.com then dev and www may conflict in the browser. Just a thought. - Can you reproduce this in an Incognito/Private window?